# "Exists" specified a single occurence, or a situation of "atleast one occurence"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have this inner-arguement over a question I've tried to solve, only to realize that (appearntly) I've misunderstood, and have been misunderstanding the function of " $\exists$ " up untill now.

Lets say we have a string, denoted $w$, where $|w|=2k$ for some $0<k\in \mathbb{N}$ and we are given that $\exists i\in \mathbb{N} : w_i=w_{k+i}$

Initially, I thought to myself, that makes sense, that there exists an index where (if we were to split $w$ to $w=u_1 \circ u_2$) $u_{1_i}\neq u_{2_i}$, and we simply "dont care" for the rest of indices.

However, a colleague suggested that this means "exists atleast one index such that...", which I find weird to comprehend.

Any enlightment on this could be helpful.

Comment: "there is a k such that U(k) is true" means the same as "it is not true that for all k U(k) is false". That is, the exist symbol means one or more, not one and only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your colleague is correct. For example, your statement is true for each of the strings $w_1=(abcade)$ and $w_2=(abcabe)$ and $w_3=(abcabc)$. The existential quantifier does not "pick out" one particular value of $i$ for you. It merely says that there is at least one value there for you to pick, allowing for the possibility that there *may* be just one value, but there may also be two or three or more.

Sometimes we use a different quantifier which says, in words, "There exists a unique $i$" and is written in symbols $\exists! i$

So we could consider a different version of your statement, namely $\exists! i \in \mathbb N : w_i=w_{k+i}$. This new statement is true for the string $w_1$ but is false for the strings $w_2$ and $w_3$.

Let me add that these are the standard logical conventions, fixed by mutual agreement (and by education). Because we have these conventions, we can all agree when we have logical discussions. These conventions are not designed to comport with any one person's intuition. Indeed that would lead to logical chaos, given that different people have different intuitions.

Comment: I see, thank you for this clarification.